# Using mutate to create a new column with the first value of each group in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm currently working on a Sabermetric research project and I've been stuck all day trying to create a new column in a data frame that displays the starting pitcher for a given game. Essentially, if I use the sample below, I have data for 'a' and 'b', but I can't figure out how to create 'c' to be the first value of 'b' for each unique value of 'a'. This should be easy, but I just started learning R.

```
    a   b   c
1   1   1   1
2   1   2   1
3   1   3   1
4   1   4   1
5   1   5   1
6   1   6   1
7   2   7   7
8   2   8   7
9   2   1   7
10  2   2   7
11  2   3   7
12  2   4   7
13  3   5   5
14  3   6   5
15  3   7   5
```

So far I've used `mutate` and `group_by` to come up with
`sample <- sample %>% group_by(a) %>% mutate(c = first(b))`
But this just makes *every* value of 'c' the first value of the first 'b'. So in the sample above, my current code makes every value of 'c' equal to 1.
I'm missing something, any suggestions?

Comment: I do not understand. Your code does produce the output you posted. What is your point? Could you please explain well.

Comment: If it works for you...I'm stumped. I've rechecked my code multiple times today and tested it many times and it still doesn't work.I currently have a season's worth of play by play baseball data that I have sorted by game and by half inning. It's essentially the pitching line for each game of the season in an endless list. I want to just include the starting pitchers, so I was planning on creating a column ('c') denoting the starting pitcher for each game. Then I could easily filter the other pitchers out with a logic statement and do the rest of what I need to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using library `dplyr`, you can do something like this:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(a) %>% mutate(c = b[1])
```

Output is as follows:

```
Source: local data frame [15 x 3]
Groups: a [3]

       a     b     c
   (int) (int) (int)
1      1     1     1
2      1     2     1
3      1     3     1
4      1     4     1
5      1     5     1
6      1     6     1
7      2     7     7
8      2     8     7
9      2     1     7
10     2     2     7
11     2     3     7
12     2     4     7
13     3     5     5
14     3     6     5
15     3     7     5
```

Changing columns to the types mentioned below in comments and running code produces desired output:

```
df$b <- as.factor(df$b)
df$a <- as.character(df$a)
str(df)
'data.frame':   15 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ a: chr  "1" "1" "1" "1" ...
 $ b: Factor w/ 8 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 1 2 ...
 $ c: int  1 1 1 1 1 1 7 7 7 7 ...

df %>% group_by(a) %>% mutate(c = b[1])
Source: local data frame [15 x 3]
Groups: a [3]

       a      b      c
   (chr) (fctr) (fctr)
1      1      1      1
2      1      2      1
3      1      3      1
4      1      4      1
5      1      5      1
6      1      6      1
7      2      7      7
8      2      8      7
9      2      1      7
10     2      2      7
11     2      3      7
12     2      4      7
13     3      5      5
14     3      6      5
15     3      7      5
```

Comment: I feel stupid. I can't even get this to work. The first time I typed it in it was fine, but once I applied it to my data it still didn't work. And I went back to the sample and now that doesn't even work. I apologize.

Comment: In the sample my variables are (dbl) instead of (int). Could that be the issue?

Comment: In my baseball data, 'a' is a (chr) and 'b' and 'c' are (fctr)

Comment: See above...using your types.

Comment: One problem can be `dplyr` version. Post result of `packageVersion('dplyr')` here. There may be a bug in your version. I am using `0.4.3` (although the new dev version is preferred over mine).

Comment: You were right about the packages, and the code works as well. THANK YOU. When I first tried your solution it worked, but in the process of testing my actual data I made a mistake. My function required the `plyr` package and messed everything up, even when I went back to the sample. I added the tiny, freaking letter 'd' to my code and it works fine. Again, I really appreciate the help. I am also using 0.4.3

Answer (score 2):

We can use `base R`

```
 df1$c <- with(df1, ave(b, a, FUN= function(x) head(x,1)))
```

---

Or with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, c:= head(b, 1), by = a]
```

Answer (score 1):

Not so elegant but it works, I hope it works for you too:

```
df1 %>% group_by(a) %>% mutate(c = rep(first(b), length(a)))
Source: local data frame [15 x 3]
Groups: a [3]

       a     b     c
   (int) (int) (int)
1      1     1     1
2      1     2     1
3      1     3     1
4      1     4     1
5      1     5     1
6      1     6     1
7      2     7     7
8      2     8     7
9      2     1     7
10     2     2     7
11     2     3     7
12     2     4     7
13     3     5     5
14     3     6     5
15     3     7     5
```