# How to fill column with values that repeat ONLY based on certain condition (and for n set of rows)? [R]

Tags: r

Some data:

```
df1 <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), 
                  
                  visit = c('screening', '1mo', '3mo', '6mo', 
'12mo', '24mo', 'screening', '1mo', '3mo', '6mo', 
'12mo', '24mo'),
                  var2 = c(20, 12, 2, 3, 67, 12, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8))
                  #var3 = c())
```

So I need to fill var3 with the correct number from var2 **ONLY** where visit == screening. So it should be whatever that value is in that first row for the subject ID, then repeated for that subject all the way through their repeated measures (all 6 rows per subject).

**I tried** using dplyr filter, multiple ifelse statements, but I just can't get it right.

**Desired output** will have var3 be equal to var2 if and only if it belongs to the screening visit.

```
#var3 = c(20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3)
```

What are some ways to accomplish this?

Comment: So what is the desired output for this sample input? What if the first value for that ID isn't "screening"? Do you always want to use the first value, or use the first "screening" value? What if there is no "screening" value at all? What should `var3` be? That way we can test possible solutions. What exactly did you try and how didn't it work?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37094600/using-mutate-to-create-a-new-column-with-the-first-value-of-each-group-in-r or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52643991/find-first-instance-per-group-and-fill-to-new-column-in-r

Comment: As per the duplicate, using `dplyr` you can do `df1 %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(var3=first(var2))`

Comment: Or `df1 %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(var3 = var2[visit == "screening"])`.

Comment: Didn't see these duplicates in my search for some reason - second link did it! Thanks @MrFlick